# String-manipulation bugs in v10.1

Tags: bugs, string-manipulation

**Introduced in 10.1, fixed in 10.2; [fixed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79173/12) via paclet update in 10.1.**

---

The new version 10.1 has introduced some strange (possibly buggy) behaviour compared to v10.0:

```
StringCases["1472", Except["0", DigitCharacter]]
```

> ```
> (* v10.0 *) {"1","4","7","2"}
> (* v10.1 *) {"1"}
> ```

Since `StringCases["1472", DigitCharacter]` returns `{"1","4","7","2"}` (all the characters) I would expect the same for an `Except[char]` pattern.

```
StringCases["1472", Except["0", DigitCharacter] ~~ "0" ... ~~ EndOfString]
```

> ```
> (* v10.0 *) {"2"}
> (* v10.1 *) {}
> ```

Further examples (thanks to Michael Hale):

```
StringReplace["1a2b3c4", Except["a", LetterCharacter] .. -> ""] (* ==> "1a2b3c4" *)
```

though even the [documentation of `Except` says](http://wolfram.com/xid/0mrbqa-ivrnc4) it should be: `"1a234"` (this should be the correct output).

```
StringCases["104702", Except["0", DigitCharacter]] (* ==> {"1", "4", "2"} *)
```

Furthermore, `ToTitleCase` removes all non-alphanumeric characters (except whitespace):

```
ToTitleCase["abcd,<>/-_=+~!@#$%&*(){}[];': end...?"] (* ==> "Abcd End" *)
```

which is probably unwanted and is definitely undocumented.

(Filed it to TechSupport, will report back if they say anything.)

---

**2015-07-29**: `ToTitleCase` is not available anymore in version 10.2 (it was experimental).

Comment: We needed a 10.0.3 with more bug fixes, not a 10.1 with *new* bugs!  >:-@

Comment: ``StringPattern`PatternConvert[Except["0", DigitCharacter]]`` gives a different result in 10.1.0.  This is the place to look to find out *why* it happens.  I don't have time to look up all the various bits needed to understand what the actual regexes do ...

Comment: @Szabolcs In 10.1.0 we upgraded the PCRE library used for much of the string pattern matching. This must have slipped through. Reported internally.

Comment: @StefanR I thought it was because the string pattern gets converted to a different regex, and not because the regex is handled differently.  10.1 produces `(?<![^0])` and 10.0 produces `(?=[^0])`.  I haven't yet had time to look up what `<!` and `=` mean here, could you maybe clarify, if you're familiar with these construct?  If I use the 10.0 regex translation in 10.1 with StringCases, I get the 10.0 behaviour.

Comment: @Szabolcs It might not be directly responsible, but the upgrade necessitated some code changes and some long-standing bugs were fixed. Some of these other changes might be responsible. The developers are investigating.

Comment: Unfortunately, in Mathematica 10.1 a number of Text Analysis functions don't work at all. I found, that *WordCount, WordCounts, LetterCounts, CharacterCounts* do nothing and suppose, that there are another non-working functions.

Comment: `I found, that WordCount, WordCounts, LetterCounts, CharacterCounts do nothing` what do you mean by they do nothing? can you show examples? on my computer with 10.1 they don't do nothing, Example `WordCount["word word word"]` gives `3`  and `WordCounts["apple apple apple"]` gives `<|"apple" -> 3|>` and `LetterCounts["aaaaaaaaaa"]` gives `<|"a" -> 10|>` Are you sure you have used these in version 10.1 and not 10.0.2?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: As a temporary workaround the version 10.0.2 regex can be obtained by evaluating ``StringPattern`Dump`rules = StringPattern`Dump`rules /. "(?<!" -> "(?=";``

Comment: @StefanR: `(?<![^0])\\d` is just plain wrong, since it means "match a digit, if it is not preceded by anything except 0", or in other words "match a digit, if it is preceded by start-of-line or 0". And this is exactly what happens in `StringCases["10230004050", RegularExpression["(?<![^0])\\d"]]`: `{"1", "2", "0", "0", "4", "5"}`.

Comment: @StefanR: and consequently also in `StringCases["10230004050", Except["0", DigitCharacter]]` or even more so in `StringCases["010230004050", Except["0", DigitCharacter]]`: `{"0", "1", "2", "0", "0", "4", "5"}`.

Comment: @SimonWoods: Your workaround does not work for `StringCases`, since the function does not seem to make use of the change.

Comment: @Jinxed, it works for me. Perhaps you saw a cached result? Could you try `ClearSystemCache[]` or a kernel reset and try again?

Comment: @SimonWoods: You were right. Interesting however, that the `Quit[]` I issued before testing your workaround obviously did not suffice to clear the system cache.

Comment: (1) Umm, @Mr. Wizard, I think it would be reasonable to say that 10.1 has, at a minimum, several hundred bug fixes. Insisting that no new ones get introduced is like insisting that the tides turn on demand. It's a complicated program and even the most experienced of developers will slip on occasion.

Comment: (2) I will say I am concerned that colleagues who check MSE might be put off by comments that, at first glance, appear to belittle the long hours they've put in (yes, we really work lots of 70 minute hours).

Comment: @Daniel (1) I sincerely apologize for any connotation of devaluing the work of you and your colleagues.  Nevertheless it seems to me that from the top down there is a misplaced emphasis on new features over making existing ones work properly (fast and bug-free).  10.0.2 still feels a lot like a beta release; a 10.0.3 with the 10.1.0 bug fixes would be highly appreciated but I don't expect it will happen.  If I can get that message across to Dr. Wolfram then my comment will have served its purpose.  And I'll point out that my comment is attracting quite a few votes of agreement.

Comment: @Daniel (2) Perhaps some day the directorial emphasis will change and the copious talents of you and your team will be brought to bear on aspects of the product that are more important to me, and as I perceive many like me.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: I strongly second, what MrWizard put forth, although I am quite sure, that we have quite different usage patterns for *Mathematica* (and, of course: him being leagues more knowledgeable ;) ).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a bug in version 10.1.0. We decided it was serious enough to warrant a fix via an automatic paclet update. The paclet has been pushed live and Mathematica should install it automatically once it does a periodic check with the paclet server. It should take about a week or so.

To install it right away, you can do
`PacletInstall["StringPatternFix"]`. You may need to restart the kernel for the fix to take effect, but after that it should work in all subsequent kernel sessions automatically.

Comment: I get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jQZaE.png) when I try it.  Perhaps it just takes a bit longer?

Comment: @Szabolcs Hmm... Does doing `PacletSiteUpdate /@ PacletSites[]` help?

Comment: [It worked today](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lXQM9.png), without `PacletSiteUpdate`.

Comment: While having full internet connectivity for everything else, it does not work for me, even with `PacletSiteUpdate`.

Comment: Running `While[Check[PacletSiteUpdate /@ PacletSites[]; 
  PacletInstall["StringPatternFix"]; False, True]]` now to automate the trial-and-error-process.

Comment: Works now. :) Thank you!

Comment: I also get same error , today 4/7/15, screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5511w.png)

Comment: Works fine on my machine (Windows 7 - 64Bit).

Comment: Sorry for commenting on this unrelated topic, but this has been bugging me ever since v10 came out: Was "Interrupt Evaluation" removed from the Evaluation menu on purpose? Or is this a bug?  I do occasionally use this feature (and the shortcut key still works in 10.0 and 10.1 fortunately).  I did ask support months ago but the response wan't very clear.  Since you're in QA I thought you would know the answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs It was deliberately removed. This is what our lead FE developer had to say about it: "[Why did I remove it]: Because it's an antiquity that is almost completely useless (and for those for whom it's not useless, I left the key binding).

Question...why is interrupting useful?
(a) If you wanted to abort, you'd just abort.
(b) If you want to continue, then why did you interrupt in the first place?
(c) If you wanted to check status, you could use any number of modern features, including Evaluate in Subsession, Monitor, PrintTemporary, etc. "

Comment: @StefanR I feel really stupid now: I somehow never noticed Evaluate in Subsession ... I do hope though that the interrupt functionality won't be removed from the kernel in the future (i.e. run kernel in terminal, press Ctrl-C, choose "i"). In order not to overload the comment thread, could we continue in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22751/interrupt)?

Answer (score 8):

Workaround for the two-argument `Except` in string patterns issue until it is fixed:

```
StringCases["104702", DigitCharacter?(! StringMatchQ[#, "0"] &)]
```

Match the second argument directly, then use `PatternTest` to check that it also doesn't match the first argument.